# Laravel 4: replicate to table

Tags: php, laravel-4, duplicates, clone, replicate

how to clone table row from one table to another i found way to make a clone but dont know how to insert it in other table

I have Data class and Product class and I want to clone from Data to Product one row only

```
 public function getClone($id) {

        $item = Data::find($id);
        $clone = $item->replicate();
        unset($clone['created_at'],$clone['updated_at']);

        $product = new Product;

      --> what goes here i tried $product->fill($clone); But i get error: 
          must be of the type array, object given

        return Redirect::to('admin/content')
            ->with('message', 'Clone Created!!');

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it when u get replicate of mysql row you get all inside json string so u need to decode it with **json_decode** function before adding it to database again so here is solution if someone has same problem :)

```
public function getClone($id) {

    $item = Data::find($id);
    $clone = $item->replicate();
    unset($clone['created_at'],$clone['updated_at']);

      $data = json_decode($clone, true);
      Product::create($data);

    return Redirect::to('admin/content')
        ->with('message', 'Clone Created!!');

}
```