# Replicate using foreign key - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, replicate

I am trying to replicate certain data in my DB and I followed the steps as in the following link. [Laravel 4: replicate to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469259/laravel-4-replicate-to-table)
However, I need to replicate some other data using only a foreign key.I tried to use the find() method to get my data but returned nothing.The where clause returns my data but in the form of array which isn't accepted by the replicate method.

Anhy idea what i am doing wrong and how can I replicate my other data?!

Code:

```
$item = Cv::find($cv_id);
        // return $item;
        $clone = $item->replicate();
        unset($clone['created_at'],$clone['updated_at']);
        $data = json_decode($clone, true);
        Cv::create($data);

        //Skills
        // return $cv_id;
        $skills = Skill::where('cv_id', $cv_id);
        $cloneSkills = $skills->replicate();
        unset($cloneSkills['created_at'],$cloneSkills['updated_at']);
        $skillData = json_decode($cloneSkills,true);
        Skill::create($skillData);
```

Comment: Where is your code or any data structure? We are not wizards

Comment: Now we have code. And what exactly doesn't work as you expect? Are any data created here?

Comment: cv part created successfully.In the skills part, only the first line works and I can't replicate the data stating Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::replicate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replicating skills you should probably use:

```
$skills = Skill::where('cv_id', $cv_id)->get();

foreach ($skills as $skill) {

    $cloneSkill = $skill->replicate();
    unset($cloneSkill['created_at'], $cloneSkill['updated_at']);
    $skillData = json_decode($cloneSkill, true);
    Skill::create($skillData);
}
```

You need to use `get()` to get all data and because `$skills` is Collection you need to use loop to replicate each skill.

Comment: OK it worked but the cv_id in Skill table wasn't changed to the new one.It stayed as the previous one. Why did that happen?

Comment: @omarsafwany Because you use the same variable to find skills `$cv_id`. If you want to use other id, you need to find in CV again another item and change `$cv_id` to its id.